# How to create multiline RadioButton with compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, radio-button, multiline

I know how to measure the size of the text, but when I increase the Size of RadioButton show me the text in one line. Is it possible to create multi-line RadioButton?
It's a compact framework 3.5.

I don't have AutoSize property. It is not a problem how to change Size, problem is they can not increase radiobutton height. I make that if I put "\r\n" in radiobutton label text, but in that case second label line is black.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a custom control for this. It's not hard, though. Create a UserControl class and have a radio button on one side and a label on the other. Hook the click event and forward it to the radio button control.